# Достать все доступные ф-ции из модуля

Tags: python, doc

Начал изучать пайтон. Увидел пример использования Urllib3. Что-то потипу:

```
>>> import urllib3
>>> http = urllib3.PoolManager()
>>> r = http.request('GET', 'http://httpbin.org/robots.txt')
```

Решил тогда посмотреть, какие же еще методы доступны для класса **PoolManager** , кроме **request**, вписал:

```
dir(urllib3.poolmanager)
```

И даже того же **reuqest** там не нашел. Пару минут позже осознал, что смотреть нужно переменную **http** на доступные уже ЕЙ методы, и там конечно же была та информация которую я искал.

Вопрос возникает следующий, есть ли возможность посмотреть доступные методы класа **PoolManager** не создавая обьект этого класа? Если вызывать документацию **help(urllib3.poolmanager)** то в ней конечно есть описанные все те методы, но есть ли возможнсть просто перечислить их в таком-же/похожем виде как это делает **dir()** , поделитесь также возможно своими способами изучения новых класов/модулей когда пробуете их лично, на ощупь.

Comment: poolmanager и PoolManager это всё-таки разные вещи

Comment: `dir(urllib3.PoolManager)`

Comment: О боже, как же можно быть таким идиотом XD Спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Вам нужен модуль `inspect`

```py
import inspect
import urllib3

print(inspect.getmembers(urllib3), sep='\n')
```